# Editing a Perforce label's description through a script

Tags: shell, command-line, perforce

I want to modify an existing Perforce label using a script that I can invoke automatically. Currently I know how to do it using the text editor option:

```
p4 label <label-name>
```

This opens up a temporary file in my default text editor, I can then enter a description, save the file and close - updates the label successfully.

However, I want to be able to do this automatically using a script. I will have variables that can be used to form my description.

I can use either a shell script or a bat script (on Windows but have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)).

Perforce command line documentation on labels can be found [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html), but it's not helping me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would do something along those lines:

```
p4 label -o  > label.txt
sed -i 's/old/new/g' label.txt  # or any other automated method to do the modification
p4 label -i < label.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be used to (easily) replace text on a single line, but `perl`'s syntax is easier when dealing with the multi-line Description field.

The following `bash` code exports the label definition for label NAME_OF_CURRENT_LABEL, creates a new label definition of MY_NEW_LABEL and then sets the description to MY_NEW_DESCRIPTION. Note that that it **assumes** that the description text exists, and is on a single line, below the "Description:" line above. To just update the description, remove the `sed` line.

```
p4 label -o NAME_OF_CURRENT_LABEL          |          # Output label spec for NAME_OF_CURRENT_LABEL     \ 
    sed 's/^Label:.*/Label: MY_NEW_LABEL/' |          # Update label name to MY_NEW_LABEL          \
    perl -pe "$/='',s/^Description:\n(.*)$/Description:\n\tMY_NEW_DESCRIPTION\n/s"  |    # Update one-line description to MY_NEW_DESCRIPTION        \
    p4 label -i                                       # Create new label with output from pipe
```